# How to: multiple-digit integer, extract each integer into an array of single integers

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, integer-arithmetic

I'm undertaking an exercise that hinges on being able to do this task. I have to take a multiple digit integer >=0, i.e. 830124, and make an array of the individual digits.

My line of thinking is that I can convert it to a string, index the string in an array, then convert back to ints, but i'm still a little lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: divide the number by 10, use the quotient and save in array..Hope this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 830124

n.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
  #=> [8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```

or, without converting characters to integers:

```
n.to_s.size.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| n,i = n.divmod(10); a.unshift(i) }
  #=> [8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct:

```ruby
830124.to_s.each_char.map(&:to_i)
# => [ 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4 ]
```

This is also really easy to do with math alone, which is probably marginally faster:

```ruby
num = 830124
arr = []

while num > 0
  num, remainder = num.divmod(10)
  arr.unshift(remainder)
end

p arr
# => [ 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4 ]
```

Comment: Any plans to be in Indianapolis next Saturday?

Comment: No..? Is there something going on there?

Comment: You're in Iowa City, right? Isn't that the home of the Iowa State Buckeyes, who are playing Michigan State in Indianapolis next Saturday for the Big 10 (football) championship? If you haven't heard about that you must be the only person in the state who hasn't. :-)

Comment: Oh, right. University of Iowa Hawkeyes, actually. I'm dimly aware of what's going on—as you say, it's impossible to live here and not be—but didn't know who or where they're playing next!